# Приспособление для лазания или лазанья?

Tags: орфография

Слово "лазания" Ворд подчеркивает как неправильное. Но "лазанья" — это блюдо итальянской кухни))) Так как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из Розенталя:

Написание -ние (-ание, -ение) или -нье (-анье, -енье) в суффиксах отглагольных существительных связано или со смысловым различием, или со стилистической дифференциацией.

1)      В смысловом отношении различаются: варение, печение, соление [процесс, то же, что «варка», «выпечка», «засол» – варенье, печенье, соленье (результат процесса, продукт); воскресение (действие по глаголу воскресить) – воскресенье (день недели); жалование (пожалование, присуждение) — жалованье (денежное вознаграждение за работу)] и т.п.

2)      Слова книжные пишутся с суффиксом -ние, слова обиходные — с суффиксом -нье, например:

а)      воспитание, достижение, замедление, искоренение, оформление, процветание, разграничение, склонение, усыновление, формирование, членение, явление;

б)      барахтанье, беганье, воркованье, дерганье, кваканье, кряхтенье, тявканье, фырканье, харканье, хихиканье, чавканье, чириканье, шиканье, щелканье.

Что касается конкретного слова лазанье/ лазание, то большинство словарей действительно дает форму лазанье. Но в толковом словаре Ефремовой - лазание.

Не поняла про лазанью.  Она-то тут причем? В языке  много разных омонимов, в том числе и омоформ.